# Cannot establish tcp connection to application launched from ant

Tags: java, ant, tcp

I implemented a simple TCP Echo server in java.
It works fine if I launch it from the command line.

But it doesn't work if I launch it from ant.
I tried both 'java' and 'exec' tasks.
The process is started correctly but the clients cannot connect to it.

Actually, local clients can establish the connection. But remote clients cannot connect to my TCP server.

Does the ant put some restrictions (sandbox?) on applications launched from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check that you are listening on the correct address. Start a shell and use netstat -ano on Windows and netstat -anp on Unix or Mac.
2. Check that your firewall allows remote connection to the port you are listening on

Comment: 1. Local clients can establish the connection. So the port is correct.
2. Remote clients can connect if I launch the application from the command line. The problem is with ant.

Comment: I did not said to check port, but to check the address. If you are listening on 127.0.0.1, you will not be able to remote connect. Do the test with command line and ant. See if there is any difference.

Comment: Of course I'm listening on the localhost.  serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port); My clients are connecting to the ip address which I got from the ipconfig.

Comment: If you are listening on the localhost (which is 127.0.0.1), then you will not be able to remote connect. `ipconfig` should not give you the localhost. Can you provide the result of the `netstat` command. This will be helpful.

Comment: Finally, it was a firewall problem. It's strange however that the firewall behavior depends on whether the tcp server was started from ant or from the command line.

Comment: Some third party firewall will allow connection depending on exe path. So, if ant use a different java.exe than your JRE, it might not get the same right.